# I am writing a reducer and action in a single file, is a good practice?

Tags: redux, react-redux

Writing reducer and action in single component will decrease my performance of app.

Answer (score 0):

File structure like that has no affect on the runtime performance at all.

We specifically [recommend using the single-file "ducks" pattern for organizing Redux logic](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#structure-files-as-feature-folders-or-ducks), and our [official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) has a [`createSlice` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) that makes that really easy.